# How can I place a circular progressView in a navigationBar with swiftui?

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, navigationbar

I have a swiftUI project and I want to place a circular progressView in the navigation bar doing the following:

```
.toolbar {
    ToolbarItem(placement: ToolbarItemPlacement.navigationBarTrailing) {
        Button {
            // some action
        } label: {
            HStack {
                ProgressView()
                    .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                    .progressViewStyle(CircularProgressViewStyle())
                Text("Save Edits")
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

The "Save Edits" appears but the progressView does not.  I'm guessing SwiftUI only allows text or images in the navigationBar as a toolbarItem.  Was wondering if there is any other approach to get the circular progressView in the navigationBar.  I see this in many apps that want to let the user know something is happening when they press the navigation bar button.

Comment: It seems the problem is the HStack in the button.  What I need to do is add two ToolbarItems and that solves the problem

Comment: You may have a look over this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O3ltwjDJaMk

Answer (score 1):

It seems the problem was having an HStack in the button.

Here is the solution in case somebody else had this problem:

```
.toolbar {
    ToolbarItem(placement: ToolbarItemPlacement.navigationBarTrailing) {
        ProgressView()
            .progressViewStyle(CircularProgressViewStyle())
    }
    ToolbarItem(placement: ToolbarItemPlacement.navigationBarTrailing) {
        Button {
            // some action
        } label: {
            
            Text("Save Edits")
        }
    }
}
```